# How to create a one-dimensional chart with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I'm trying to do is to replicate a single line of this chart:

[image: spatial voting chart]

It doesn't have to be exactly the same, but following the same idea. I'd like to be able to draw a single line as well. Something like:

> ----Y--Y--Y--|--N--N--N--N----

So far, the closest I got was using ggplot2's `theme()` to hide the axis, but didn't come up with something I liked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would make the question easier to answer if you provided a short sample of the data you were working with. Assuming you have something like this:

```
votes <- data.frame(vote=paste(1:7),
                    how=c(rep("Y", 3), rep("N", 4)),
                    legislator=c(rep("L1", 7) ) )
```

You might create a chart something like this:

```
ggplot(votes, aes(x=vote, y=legislator) ) +
  geom_text(aes(label=how)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1.05)) +
  geom_segment(x=3.5, xend=3.5, y=0.95, yend=1.05, size=1.5)
```

If you want an empty theme, start with something like this: (from https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3711166)

```
new_theme_empty <- theme_bw()
new_theme_empty$line <- element_blank()
new_theme_empty$rect <- element_blank()
new_theme_empty$strip.text <- element_blank()
new_theme_empty$axis.text <- element_blank()
new_theme_empty$plot.title <- element_blank()
new_theme_empty$axis.title <- element_blank()
new_theme_empty$plot.margin <- structure(c(0, 0, -1, -1),
                                         unit = "lines",
                                         valid.unit = 3L,
                                         class = "unit")
```

And use it like this:

```
ggplot(votes, aes(x=vote, y=legislator) ) +
  geom_text(aes(label=how)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1.05)) +
  geom_segment(x=3.5, xend=3.5, y=0.95, yend=1.05, size=1.5) +
  new_theme_empty
```

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLwLV.jpg